# jQuery Mobile: Scroll only the listview

Tags: jquery, html, css, listview, jquery-mobile

I'm "translating" an Android Native App int an Hybrid jQuery App and I'm trying to emulate some behaviours that the nativa app has by default.

This is the android app and its behaviour when I scroll the listview:

[image]
[image]

As you can see when I scroll, ONLY the listview is scrolled.

Instead in the hybrid application when i scroll, EVERYTHING in that page scroll (except the header and the footer that have the data-position setted to fixed).

[image] 
[image]

Comment: What about placing the "scrollable" (middle div) content in a div with the `height:100%` `overflow-x: hidden;` and `overflow-y: scroll;` -- You may have to use top and bottom padding to get where you need to be, but --  Would that not accomplish what you are trying?  Instead of "fixed" elements,you could do --> header `div`, middle `div` (scrollable) and footer `div` just stacked.

Comment: I tryed it and it works well but the problem is that when I reach the bottom of the listview it keeps scrolling and hide the Combo box

Comment: It would seem then, that you have an outer an inner div, both scrollable ... when the inner div is done scrolling, the outer will scroll.  Try putting the combo box at the bottom of the header, or un-nest the divs.

Comment: This is crude, but it illustrates my point : http://jsfiddle.net/GXj4u/

Comment: I resolved like this: I give to the page a class "no-scroll" in which I set overflow:hidden and everything works well... ThankYou very much

Answer (score 2):

I am using Jquery Mobile.And It is working for me.Here is the code-

```
 <div data-role="page" id="page-one">    
    <div id="header" data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        HEADER
    </div> //end of header div

    <div data-role="content" id="content">
       <ul data-role="listview" class="list-view" data-inset="true">
         <li>List 1</li>
           .
           .
      </ul> 
   </div> //end of content div

   <div id="footer" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
      FOOTER
   </div> //end of footer div

</div> //end of page div

And the css for class "list-view",such as-   
.list-view {    
            height: set height for the list.    
            top: set top pixel for the list.    
                 .   
                 .   
            overflow: auto;   
            -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;   
           }
```

Hope it will help you.Thank you.